# PHP: Populate a specific value of an array, defined by a key, with variables

Tags: php, arrays, variables, syntax, message

I'm trying to populate a specific value of an array, defined by a key with, variables.
The value holds a form for a syntax, the key is the identifier for it.

I'm not sure if this is the right way to this, but it's where I am having trouble:

```
function create_mess($data){
    echo message_list($data);   
    }

function message_list($data){
    $messages = array(
        1000 => $data['user']." logged on!",
        2000 => $data['user']." comment on ".$data['user_rep']."s comment about!".$data['title'],
        2010 => "You just received a reply to".$data['title']."by ".$data['user'],
        3000 => $data['user'].": ".$data['title']."!"
    );

    return $messages[$data['mess_id']];
    }
```

This is a trimmed down version of what I have in order to make things more clear. I'm aware that the `create_mess` function isn't a very useful one right now.

Currently it always fills in all the variables. What I want to know is:

- Is it possible to only fill in the variables for the identifier key you pass through the function?
- Is this possible with an array?
- Or only if these sentences are stored in a DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach($messages as $key => &$message)
        if($key != $data['mess_id'])
            unset($messages[$data['mess_id']];
```

this will just strip down the array after having filled in all the values (inefficient).  If you want to conditionally fill the array, you'll have to build some logic around the creation of the array you want to return based on the message id.  For example: treat your current messages array as a "template" to build a secondary array you will return.

Comment: Good idea! I'll try using the current messages array as a template.
I'll try using replacement syntax '%var' and such in sentences. Than fill it in.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, yes. You can declare the arguments as null:
    function create_mess($key1=null, $key2=null) { etc... }

You can pass it as an array then use [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php):
    function create_mess($array) { list($key1, $key2)=$array; }

If this isn't what you're looking for, you'll have to be a little more specific.

Comment: It's not really what I am looking for. Or at least, I can't make it work with list(). Thanks though!